# Non-zero eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As a part of an exercise I have to prove the following:

Let $A$ be an $(n \times m)$ matrix. Let $A^T$ be the transposed matrix of $A$. Then $AA^T$ is an $(n \times n)$ matrix and $A^TA$ is an $(m \times m)$ matrix. $AA^T$ then has a total of $n$ eigenvalues and $A^TA$ has a total of $m$ eigenvalues.

What I need to prove is the following:

$AA^T$ has an eigenvalue $\mu \not = 0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $A^TA$ has an eigenvalue $\mu \not = 0$

In other words, they have the same non-zero eigenvalues, and if one has more eigenvalues than the other, then these are all equal to $0$.

How can I prove this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: In fact, if $n\geq m$ then $\text{det}(\lambda I_n - AA^T )=\lambda^{n-m}\text{det}(\lambda I_m - A^TA ).$

Comment: how can we prove this with counting geometric multiplicities?

Answer (score 84):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A^TA$, i.e. $$A^T A x = \lambda x$$
for some $x \neq 0$. We can multiply $A$ from the left and get
$$A A^T (Ax) = \lambda (Ax).$$

What can you conclude from this?

Comment: what happens if $x \in ker(A)?$ not that it can happen.

Comment: @abel If $Ax=0$, then $\lambda x=0$ and $\lambda=0$. So, if we assume $\lambda\ne0$…

Comment: @egreg, i know; but that needed to be part of the answer. egret you must like linear. this is the second time we meet, the other one at eigenvalues 1, -1, and 4.

Comment: Further, same proof holds for any $A$ and $B$ as mentioned by @abel. Given $ABx = \lambda x$, multiplying by $B$, yields $BABx = B \lambda x$ $\Rightarrow$ $BA(Bx) = \lambda (Bx)$. So, $AB$ and $BA$ share the eigenvalues.

Comment: Answers should not pose further questions without answering them themselves. This site is not for teaching the OP, it is for reference.

Answer (score 22):

in fact, nonzero eigenvalues $AB$ and $BA$ are the same for any rectangular matrices
$A$ and $B$. this follows from the fact that $trace((AB)^k) = trace((BA)^k)$ and the coefficients of the characteristic polynomials of a square matrix $A$ are a function of $trace(A^k).$

Comment: So we can we say that the non-zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ also have the same algrebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 8):

One proof that comes to mind is to use [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem).

In particular:
$$
\mu \neq 0 \text{ is an eigenvalue of }A^TA  \implies\\
\det(A^TA - \mu I) = 0 \implies\\
\det(I + (-1/\mu)A^TA) = 0 \implies\\
\det(I + A(-1/\mu)A^T) = 0 \implies\\
\det(AA^T - \mu I) = 0 \implies\\
\mu \neq 0 \text{ is an eigenvalue of }AA^T
$$

Answer (score 8):

[SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is definitely an overkill, but maybe it would be helpful to you (as it is for me) to draw the matrices that the decomposition gives us:

[image: SVD]

Recall that:

- The columns of $V$ (right-singular vectors) are eigenvectors of
  $A^TA$.
- The columns of $U$ (left-singular vectors) are eigenvectors
  of $AA^T$.
- $V^T=V^{-1}$ and $U^T=U^{-1}$.

With some simple operations you can get:

[image: derived from SVD 1]

And also:

[image: derived from SVD 2]

Write down both of these equations, but for the $i^\text{th}$ column.
From there, the solution is not far.