# Why is $\max_{c^TBc=1}c^T a a^Tc =a^TB^{-1}a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'm having some trouble in understanding the last step in this sequence of equalities:

$$\max_{c}\frac{c^Taa^Tc}{c^TBc}=\max_{c^TBc=1}c^T a a^Tc =a^TB^{-1}a$$

I would think that the maximum would be equal the biggest eigenvalue of the matrix $B^{-1}aa^T$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $B$ is positive definite. Defining $x=B^{1/2}c$ the problem is
$$
\max_{c^TBc=1}|a^Tc|^2=\max_{\|x\|=1}|a^TB^{-1/2}x|^2=\|B^{-1/2}a\|^2=a^TB^{-1}a.
$$

EDIT: the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}aa^T$ are the same as the eigenvalues of the (similar) matrix $B^{-1/2}aa^TB^{-1/2}$, which has [the same nonzero eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087064/non-zero-eigenvalues-of-aat-and-ata) as the matrix (actually, number) $a^TB^{-1/2}B^{-1/2}a=a^TB^{-1}a$. Your conclusion is right: the maximum is the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1}aa^T$, and it is $a^TB^{-1}a$.

Comment: Much obliged ;)

Comment: Dear A.G., by the way, how does one prove the 1st equality in my question. I thought I could do it, but it's taking a bit more time than I though. A hint should suffice. ;)

Comment: Also, how does one prove the second equality in your answer? I thought I understood it...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The 1st equality in the question follows from the fact that both numerator and the denominator are homogeneous in $c$, so if $c^TBc=\rho^2\ne 1$ it is possible to consider $\tilde c=\frac{c}{\rho}$.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. One way to understand the second equality is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $u^Tv=\langle u,v\rangle\le\|u\|\|v\|$ with equality iff $u$ and $v$ are parallel.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Lagrange multiplier to show it, i.e., you problem is equivalent to 
$$
\arg \max_{c, \lambda} \left( c'Ac - \lambda (c'Bc - 1) \right),
$$
where $A = aa'$. The first order condition is 
$$
2Ac - 2\lambda Bc=0,
$$
i.e., 
$$
Ac=\lambda Bc,
$$
that is a generalized eigenvalue problem. If $B$ is invertible, then 
$$
B^{-1}Ac=\lambda c,
$$ 
that is the vector $c$ that satisfies the F.O.C, must satisfy this linear, which is by the definition pairs of eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$. As such, the final question is which pair to choose? So, going back to the original formulation you have in the nominator
$$
c'Ac=c' \lambda_A c = \lambda_A \sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2,
$$ 
where the pair of largest eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A$ correspond to the same pair in $B^{-1}A$.

Alternatively you can use even more basic calculus to show it. Recall that 
$$
\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)' = \frac{f'g - fg'}{ g^ 2 },
$$
hence the F.O.C is, 
$$
\left(\frac{c'Ac}{c'Bc} \right)' = \frac{2Ac c'Bc - 2c'AcBc}{(c'Bc)^2} = 0,
$$
rewriting the LHS and multiplying both sides by $c'Bc/2$ you have
$$
Ac -  Bc\frac{ c'Ac }{c'Bc} = 0,
$$
Note that $\frac{ c'Ac }{c'Bc}$ is a (positive) scalar, so denote it by $\lambda$, thus you'll get the generalized eigenvalue problem, i.e., 
$$
Ac = \lambda B c, 
$$ 
hence as previously you have 
$$
B^{-1}Ac = \lambda c,
$$ 
i.e., the mximum is attained for $c$ that is eigenvector of $B^{-1} A$ and the maximum value equals its largest eigenvalue.