# How to find eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an m×n matrix with $m$<$n$ and rank$(A) =m$. If $B=AA^T$ , $C=A^TA$ and the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $B$ are known, find the non-zero eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $C$

My thinking: Since rank$(A)=m$, rank$(B)=m$, rank$(C) =m$. Hence $C$ has $m$ non zero eigenvalues. $A$ is not a square matrix. If an eigenvalue of $B$ is $\alpha$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $x$ then $Bx=\alpha x$.
I can't proceed further. Please help me. Thank you in advance...

Comment: hint: B and C have the same nonzero eigenvalues, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087064/non-zero-eigenvalues-of-aat-and-ata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have,

$$Bx = \alpha x \\
(AA^\top)x = \alpha x \\
A^\top (AA^\top) x = A^\top \alpha x \\
(A^\top A) A^\top x= \alpha A^\top x \\
CA^\top x = \alpha A^\top x $$
Let $A^\top x = q \ \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then we have,

$$Cq = \alpha q$$
This shows that the eigenvectors of C are the eigenvectors of B multiplied by $A^\top$. What about the eigenvalues? We have $m$ distinct eigenvalues of B, but C has $n$ eigenvalues. Well as you guessed correctly, C is of rank(m), so it has $n-m$ zero eigenvalues, and the other $m$ eigenvalues are same as B.

Comment: What are the eigenvectors corresponding eigen value 0?

Comment: To find the zero eigenvectors you are solving Cq = 0, so q is the null-space of C.